# It's possible to create a proton colliding a positron with enough energetic photons?

Tags: nuclear-physics, proton-decay

If a proton is supposed to decay in a positron and gamma ray photons is possible to obtain the opposite process colliding enough energetic photons with a positron and create a proton ?

Comment: Most (it used to be all, but kaons and D-mesons and stuff...) microscopic processes in physics exhibit time-reversal invariance, but as a practical matter anything involving proton decay has such vanishingly small cross-section that we would no more be able to go after the inverse processes experimentally than we can go after evidence of string theory by a naive search for the structure of the leptons.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing you're referring to the original model of proton decay that arose from the first grand unified theories:

[image: Proton decay]

([picture from here](http://www.quantumdiaries.org/2012/06/02/how-to-discover-new-physics/)). The proton decays to a positron and a neutral pion, and the pion then decays to two gamma particles with a half life of $8.4 \times 10^{−17}$ seconds. So to make protons you would have to get two gamma ray photons to produce a pion, then within $8.4 \times 10^{−17}$ seconds that pion would have to react with a positron to create a leptoquark and that in turn would have to decay to the two up quarks. Even if leptoquarks exist, this would be a very, very improbable process.

Comment: There has been more experimental interest in the kaon channel recently because it is much easier to extract from the background even if it is suppressed relative the pion channel by a moderate factor.

Comment: @dmckee: have you got a reference? I'll edit it into my answer.

Comment: The [LBNE document written for the recent "Snowmass" process](http://arxiv.org/abs/arXiv:1307.7335) has some discussion and references.

Answer (score 0):

Proton Decay is currently a completely hypothetical process, as far as recall there isn't actually any experimental evidence to back up the prediction.

If however we assume that proton decay is possible into photons and a positron. Then yes it would be possible to do the reverse. The problem with this however is how to hit a positron with enough photons simultaneously, if one photon hits the electron before the others it will cause it to Compton scatter away and thus the other photons will miss.

This a purely hypothetical experiment however and it would be hard to prove it true or false. I suppose you can also assume that if the forward process is possible the reverse will be by time reversal.

Comment: While it is purely hypothetical it is present in all the leading contenders for a next generation theory (and because it pops up, not because people are putting it there). That's one of the reasons for the persistent interest in looking for it: it *seems* to be necessary.